# How to check vue is working after relaunching VS workspace - vue stops rendering?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm following tutorial, relaunched the vs studio workspace, F5 on the localhost shows that vue js is not working.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>erjan_vue</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>

<div id ="vue-app">
 <h1>computer propertis</h1> 
<button v-on:click="a++">add to a</button>
<button v-on:click="b++">add to b</button>
<p> A - {{a}}</p>
<p> B - {{b}}</p>
<p> age + a = {{addToA()}}</p>
<p> age + b = {{addToB()}}</p>
</div>

    <script src = "main.js"></script>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
body{
    background-color: bisque;
    border:10px solid red;
}
div{
    padding:200px 20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px; 
    text-align: center;  
}
```

main.js:
    import Vue from 'vue'
    Vue.config.productionTip = false
    new Vue({

```
  el: '#vue-app',
  data:{
    age:20,
    a:0,
    b:0
  },      
  methods:{
    addToA:function(){ console.log("");return this.a + this.age;},
    addToB:function(){ return this.b + this.age;}
    }
})
```

[image: kk]

The {{a}} brackets should be showing actual numbers.

Comment: looks like Vue is not initiated at all. what error are you getting in browser console ?

Comment: @JacobGoh, oh right, newbie stupid mistake. the main.js is in subfolder! thx u

Comment: By the way, it is better to use computed values instead of methods for addToA or addToB. You can check it out here, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html.

Comment: @JacobGoh, i have this error in my main.js file - "Import Vue from 'vue' - unexpected identifier

Comment: that's a very new JS systax that is not supported in browser.  the javascript ecosystem can seem messy if you are just getting started. You may read this [article](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f) to get a sense of it. But anyway, I suggest you to start with vue-cli, instead of setting it all up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, deleting the

```
Import Vue from 'vue'
```

worked, but also if you dont include this:

```
<title>erjan_vue</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

without this line, entire Vue fails and can't render.

Check the path to js file, in my case - main.js.